# PHP Date Function Gives Me A Wrong Time

Tags: php, mysql

I have a php datetime function that is used to insert the current date and time into mySQL database. However the date gives the right date but a wrong time any suggestion.

Below is the code.

```php
/* Get Current Date and Time for the bookking_time field */
$booking_time=new DateTime();
$booking_time = $booking_time -> format("Y-m-d H:i:s");


// Create connection
$con = new mysqli($servername, $username, $password, $dbname , 3306);


if ($con->connect_error) {
    die("Connection failed: " . $con->connect_error);
}  

 //mysql_select_db("$database", $con);
 $sql= "INSERT INTO data_centre_users (fisrt_name,last_name,request,purpose,description,booking_time,approved)
VALUES ('$first','$last','$request','$purpose','$description','$booking_time','$approval')"; 

if ($con->query($sql) === TRUE) {
    echo "New record created successfully";
} else {
    echo "Error: " . $sql . "<br>" . $con->error;
}
```

any suggestion to fix the problem

Comment: you need to check timezone date_default_timezone_get()

Comment: What's wrong about the time?

Comment: @RowlandShaw: I'm sure that it's just because of different `timezne` set by `PHP`.

Comment: Check the default timezone configured in php.ini or set a custom timezone to your application. Sometimes it might be your server time that is incorrect.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It might be simpler to use the SQL Syntax `NOW()` to get the date and time.

```
$sql= "INSERT INTO data_centre_users 
       (fisrt_name,last_name,request,purpose,
        description,booking_time,approved)
       VALUES ('$first','$last','$request',
               '$purpose', '$description', NOW(), '$approval')";
```

You may have also spelt `fisrt_name` wrong, but I cannot know that for sure.

Comment: Wow, they finally got a spelling checker on SO. Great

Answer (score 2):

Set the timezone in the very beginning of your script file, using date_default_timezone_set();

Suppose in my case my timezone is Indian/Maldives then it would be

```
date_default_timezone_set('Indian/Maldives');
```

For a list of supported timezones refer to http://php.net/manual/en/timezones.php

Comment: Ohh not fair, working in the Maldives. How do you stay away from the diving?

Comment: Might be worth checking the timezone used by the MySQL Server as well as PHP.

Comment: @RiggsFolly you wont believe, 23+ years and still not a single dive

Answer (score 0):

First of check your `date_default_timezone_set();` is proper set or not then Try like this `$booking_time = date('Y-m-d H:i:s');`